# vue + meteor not compiling after npm update today - 'mapState' is readOnly

Tags: meteor, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I decided to upgrade my modules after updating my mongo engine to wiredtiger. Suddenly the compiler is throwing strange readOnly errors - not only with vuex imports, but components. Here is my console output:

```
=> Errors prevented startup:
 While building for web.browser:
 imports/vue/root.vue:70: [vue-component] Error while compiling in tag
 <script> col:66: C:/src/app/imports/vue/root.vue:
 "mapState" is read-only
 imports/vue/home.vue:5: [vue-component] Error while compiling in tag
 <script> col:62: C:/src/app/imports/vue/home.vue:
 "mainmap" is read-only
 imports/vue/login.vue:7: [vue-component] Error while compiling in tag
 <script> col:68: C:/src/app/imports/vue/login.vue:
 "Template" is read-only
 imports/vue/logout.vue:5: [vue-component] Error while compiling in tag
 <script> col:73: C:/src/app/imports/vue/logout.vue:
 "users" is read-only
```

Note that I am using the "vue": "git://github.com/mitar/vue.git#meteor", fork of vue in my package.json. Using a stack from the /meteor-vue/vue-meteor github project.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a meteor package version issue. Reverting my meteor versions file to previous state solved it.